# text adventure game, looping troubleshooting

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I am creating a text adventure game, as practice. 
And I have been working on this adventure game for quite sometime... 
I mainly used the if, elif, and else statements for 90% of the code... (complete code not shown, the code below is only a portion)
My code has MANY layers, and I was trying to figure out how to loop that does not require to be on the same same indention levels, I am wondering if anyone could help me with this?
Do I have to re-think the format of the code? or can I use my existing code filled with else, if and elif functions?

I cannot figure out how to use the while and for loops in my situation for the life of me.

```py
#setup
name = ('Ashe')
robot_name = ('bob')
status = []
#status is the "players life.  1=alive; 0=dead"
#game_start (not really) many more layers of code supposed to be before these... the decision the user leads to here...
answer = input('input either 1 or 2')
if (answer == "1"):
    #there are many layers and "decisions here"
    print(f"""{robot_name}:[let me get through this wall of bright blue vines] """)
    print(f"""{robot_name}:[There is a LOT of these vines, maybe this IS the wa---] """)
    print(f"""{robot_name}:[We wandered into a tar pit... there does not seem to be anything to help us...] """)
    print(f"""{robot_name}:[I am sinking FAST... {name} I don't think I will make it... I will keep this brief] """)
    print(f"""{robot_name}:[Thank you for everything thus far, please do not blame youself for this... and... goodbye...] """)
    print(f"""User [{name}] - Disconnected from unit {robot_name}."you died" """)
    #how to make this point loop back to "#game_start" 
if (answer == '2'): 
    #many layers added here
    answer = input(f"""you are still alive and finished the game. would you like to play again?' (yes/no)""")
    if answer == ('yes'):
        print('alright, we will start the game again')
        #many more layers, how to loop back to start?
    elif answer == ('no'):
        print('guess not')
        #loop back to start

else:
    print('not working?')
    #loop back to start
```

I am trying to make the code loop back to the start or middle of the code regardless of any and all decisions.  despite having different levels of indention.

Comment: Do you just want the whole thing to loop? If so, just put `While True:` at the top above your first if statement and indent everything below it. If you want to be able to be able to break from that loop write `While (a == b):` and then set b ≠ a somewhere later. Am I understanding the question?

Comment: This really helps! I could use this throughout the code depite indention levels?  also is it possible to have a while statement within a while statement?

Comment: Yes, you can nest while loops and that will work at any indentation level. It is important to note that the while loop executes all of its code before checking its condition again (e.g. `while a == 0: ; a = 1 ; print("Hi")` will print Hi even though you set a to 1 before your print statement).